# JavaScript Double Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with 3 Select Box's I have. The second and third should populate after select the first and second select box.

After select a value from Select Box 1, it populates Select Box 2.
After select a value from Select Box 2, it populates Select Box 3.

I have two problems with my code:

- It populates automatically the second select box based on first value, but doesn't populate the third select box
- After change it populates the select box, but If I change the first select box, it updates the second select box but the third isn't updated based on the values of the second select box. It only populates after I change the value in the second select box.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category").change(function(){ 
        getSubCat();//get sub category after change event
    });
    $("#subcategory").change(function(){ 
        getSubSubCat(); //get sub category after change event
    });
    getSubCat();//get sub category after page load
    getSubSubCat();
    function getSubCat(){
        var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subcat.php",
            data: { category : selectedCategory } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#subcategory").html(data);
        });
    }
    function getSubSubCat(){
        var selectedSubCategory = $("#subcategory option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subsubcat.php",
            data: { subcategory : selectedSubCategory } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#subsubcategory").html(data);
        });
    }        
});
</script>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.done()` function of `getSubCat()` should call `getSubSubCat()`.

```
function getSubCat(){
    var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subcat.php",
        data: { category : selectedCategory } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#subcategory").html(data);
        getSubSubCat();
    });
}
```

When you call `getSubSubCat()` during page load, `getSubCat()` hasn't finished yet (because AJAX is asynchronous), so none of its changes to the second menu have been made.